# Waterfall chart for different groups without facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a waterfallchart with several groups where all the groups start at 0.

This is my code:

```
gdp <- data.frame("Country"=rep(c("China", "USA"), each=2),
                  "Type"=rep(c("GDP2013", "GDP2014"), 2),
                  "Cnt"= c(16220, 3560, 34030, -10570))

gdp <- gdp %>%
  mutate(start=Cnt,
         start=lag(start),
         end=ifelse(Type=="GDP2013", Cnt, start+Cnt),
         start=ifelse(Type=="GDP2013", 0, start),
         amount=end-start,
         id=rep(1:2, each=2))


gdp %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=Type)) +
  geom_rect(stat="identity", aes(x=Country, 
                xmin=id-0.25, 
                xmax=id+0.25, 
                ymin=start, 
                ymax=end))
```

The two bar types should be ordered next to each other per group and USA GDP2014 should start at the height of USA GDP2013 but end 10570 lower.

I know that I could do this with a [facet_wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050698/convert-dataframe-to-make-waterfall-chart-in-ggplot2) but I want no separation between groups (e.g. facets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_rect` takes a `position` parameter.

I believe `position='dodge'` does what you require if I understand your question correctly.

[image]

More info: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Great, could you please mark the answer as accepted? that will help others see that this question is solved.